# RDLC in MVC application not viewed in deploy on IIS 10

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, rdlc, intranet

MVC 4 application with rdlc report. work ok locally in visual studio. Deployed in IIS 10 (intranet), it return blank page.

On the same IIS (intranet server) I have published other applications with rdlc reports and they work perfectly. The configuration of all application in IIS seem to be identical.

Answer (score 0):

I put the RenderReport code into a try-catch statement and register the error in deploy using nlog... The result is that in deploy was missing (I don't know why) Microsoft.SQLServer.Types.dll, I copy it in \bin folder and then the report is ok.